# PIC32, USB CDC + HID Composite Device fails with Code 10

Tags: pic, usb, microchip, usb-device

I've been busy building a CDC + HID composite USB device for the past couple of weeks, and stuck with **This device cannot start. (Code 10)** error in Windows 7.

When looking at the device through USBlyzer, I can see the device successfully communicates with the PC, as USBlyzer is able to extract both the USB device and configuration descriptors. USBlyzer isn't pointing out any errors, making it difficult to see what exactly is wrong.

My code is available at [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/sparkbuzz/pic32_usb.x/src), the Mercurial repository URL is https://bitbucket.org/sparkbuzz/pic32_usb.x.

The project is really simple, and there are basically three important files:

- [main.c](https://bitbucket.org/sparkbuzz/pic32_usb.x/src/3e576855a784e82ab255a43e084ba7ea422e5f7e/main.c?at=default) - The main application source.
- [usb_config.h](https://bitbucket.org/sparkbuzz/pic32_usb.x/src/3e576855a784e82ab255a43e084ba7ea422e5f7e/usb_config.h?at=default) - Some configuration defines.
- [usb_descriptors.h](https://bitbucket.org/sparkbuzz/pic32_usb.x/src/3e576855a784e82ab255a43e084ba7ea422e5f7e/usb_descriptors.c?at=default) - USB device and configuration descriptors.

The project is basically derived from the **Device - Composite - MSD + CDC** example from [Microchips' Libraries for Applications](http://www.microchip.com/mla). I've double checked that descriptor size values are correct, and been over the code a dozen times, but not sure what's causing my headaches.

My breadboard setup looks like this, and it is working quite well, since I've tested it with an HID only example, and it worked perfectly *(So the problem is definitely somewhere in my code)*:

[image]

The setup uses a [PIC32MX250F128B MCU from Microchip](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en557425), with an LDO on the top right which steps the VUSB 5V down to 3.3V for the MCU Vdd supply. A 12MHz crystal supplies a clock signal to the MCU, which is used to configure the USB Module clock to 48MHz (see configuration bits in the source code). The green LED lights up when **USBDeviceState == CONFIGURED_STATE** and the red LED simply indicates that the 3.3V supply is on.

The device is visible in Device Manager:

[image]

...but off course Windows 7 isn't happy:

[image]

Here's the report from USBlyzer:

[image]

Some more output from USBTrace, could the problem be to do with configuration selection?

[image]

I have no idea what's wrong, and have been trying this entire week to fix this.

Please can someone try to help?

Comment: Have you tried compiling one of the sample Microchip applications without making any changes and see if it works?

Comment: Not without changing them, no. I managed to get the HID portion working, adding the CDC is where the issues are. I'll give the Microchip CDC Basic Demo a go, on its own. Not a bad idea.

Comment: I've added another image, USBTrace is throwing out a STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL error on SELECT_CONFIGURATION. Not entirely sure what it means yet.

Comment: Just reading the MLA docs, and it mentions I might need a .inf file for Windows?

Comment: I think I need to write a driver for Windows! On Mac, I can see the device sitting under /dev/tty.usbmodemfd122

Comment: I haven't tried HID+CDC, but HID+MSD works fine for me on windows. Sometimes Windows has some issues when the same VID+PID combination is used for different USB classes as is common when during development, because it caches the information, and this causes it to not detect the device properly. I use a tool called USBDview.exe to clean up the associations. You should also try the Microchip USB forums, there are quite a experts there who should be able to help you.

Comment: I have posted on Microchip forum, for days, there hasn't been a response to my thread. I'll look out for USBDview.exe. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: This might help a bit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176939/do-i-need-to-write-my-own-host-side-usb-driver-for-a-cdc-device I haven't added a .inf file, so need to go learn how to. :)

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using? I have just spent 2 weeks writing an entire PIC32 usb stack in C++ for the chipKIT environment, and I know that windows can be a relay PITA. Even with $800 worth of USB debugging hardware it was being annoying...